# Why isn't GA4 debug viewer showing most events when it was working this morning

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Hi I've been using GA4 debug viewer most of today and everything has been fine until I went away from my computer for about 2 hours, came back without changing anything in my GTM setup up and for some reason barely any events are being received in the debug viewer anymore.

Sometimes an add_to_cart or pageview will appear but most of the time nothing is coming through other than user engagement, at least most of the time.

I've tried using different browsers, disabling every tag except ga4 config for the page view and nothing appears to fix it.

Is this an issue with Ga4 debugview or something on my end?

I also had the exact same issue yesterday, came on today hoping it would be fixed, it was for a few hours and just like yesterday I went away from my computer for a few hours for it to randomly start happening again.

I can't find anything on this issue.